# c# - How to get property value from derived class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am writing a console app in C#.

Here is the code:

```
interface ITest
{
    string str { get; }
}

public class BaseClass : ITest
{
    public virtual string str
    {
        get
        {
            return "BaseClass";
        }
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new string str {
        get {
            return "DerivedClass";
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ITest itest = new DerivedClass();

        Console.WriteLine(itest.str);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When i am executing the above code, "BaseClass" is coming as the output. Instead, how do i get "DerivedClass" as output?

Comment: Drop the `new` qualifier and replace it with `override`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With declaring the property with `new` in your derived class you're creating a new member which isn't called when invoked through the interface. Use `override` instead.

Answer (score 9):

You need to `override` the virtual property instead of making a `new` one:

```
public override string str 
{
    get 
    {
        return "DerivedClass";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer @Janne Matikainen :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `dynamic` type to access the runtime type directly.

```
Itest itest = new DerivedClass();
var str = ((dynamic)itest).str; // str == "DerivedClass"
```

This is needed if you override a method with the `new` keyword instead of `override`.

Comment: omg... no way :P

Comment: I can't believe that just worked..Why aren't people talking about this.